# Python3 asyncio event loops and task cancelling

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-3.10

I have been trying to understand the `asyncio` module in order to
implement a server. I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897428/please-explain-task-was-destroyed-but-it-is-pending-after-cancelling-tasks) question, which seems
to ask a similar, if not the same question, however I am still trying
to grasp the workflow happening behind the sceens.

I have the following simple program that has two coroutines, one reading from the terminal
and putting it into a Queue and one coroutine that waits for items in the queue and
simply prints them back to the screen.

```py
import asyncio

q = asyncio.Queue()

async def put():
    while True:
        await q.put(input())      #Input would be normaly something like client.recv()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)    #This is neccessarry but I dont understand why

async def get():
    while True:
        print(await q.get())

def run():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task1 = loop.create_task(put())
    task2 = loop.create_task(get())
    loop.run_forever()

run()
```

This program works as expected, however when one removes the `await asyncio.sleep(1)`
statement from the `put` method, it stops working. I assume because the loop keeps eating up the thread and the message doesn't get pushed through. I don't understand why though because I would think `input()` would be a blocking function and the coroutine should thus suspend until a new line is available on the tty.

---

The second problem is, if I use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` in the `run()` call, the interpreter warns me that there is no active loop, however, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) this call is deprecated and thus I tried replacing it with `asyncio.new_event_loop()`. The programm still works the same, however I get a traceback upon KeyboardInterrupt (which does **not** happen when calling `asyncio.get_event_loop()`)

```sh
Task was destroyed but it is pending!                                                         
task: <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<put() running at test.py:10> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>             
Task was destroyed but it is pending!                                                       
task: <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<get() running at test.py:15> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>               
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object get at 0x7f32f51369d0>                              
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                          
  File "test.py", line 15, in get     
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/asyncio/queues.py", line 161, in get                     
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon          
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed     
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

---

A third variant I tried was to make the run method itself async and call it via the `asyncio.run(run())` call.

```
import asyncio

q = asyncio.Queue()

async def put():
    while True:
        await q.put(input())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def get():
    while True:
        print(await q.get())


async def run():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task1 = loop.create_task(put())
    task2 = loop.create_task(get())
    await task1

asyncio.run(run())
```

This works just fine as well, however if I replace `await task1` with `await task2`,
again I get errors when I interrupt the program.
Why is the execution different between these and how is it supposed to be done in the end?

Comment: Complex question, I can answer it later on, but first, have you read about how asyncio works? Normal blocking functions shouldn't be used together with aio.

Comment: Indeed I was just using input() for the MWE, in my application I use `StreamReader` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303607/python-asyncio-how-to-read-stdin-and-write-to-stdout)

Comment: So with `StreamReader` problem #1 will work flawlessly. `input()` does not give a chance for aio to switch coroutines.

Comment: Unless you constantly have data, in which case you'd want to limit the queue to a certain length. Do you want me to elaborate on that or regarding the coroutine switching?

Comment: I appreciate the answer already. I think I understand the problem that the coroutine would keep occupying the thread trying to fill up the queue, so limiting the length will force the read() call to pause. I guess I am more confused why the different versions raise different erros.

Comment: different versions?

Comment: Uhm, bad choice of words. I meant why it makes such a big difference between using `get_event_loop()` and `new_event_loop()` and in the last example between `await task1` and `await task2`, as well as what is the difference between `loop.run_forever()` in the first two cases and `asyncio.run(run())` in the last case

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, with `StreamReader` (your original code) problem #1 will work flawlessly and cause no issue. `input()` does not give a chance for aio to switch coroutines, and you can try and limit the queue to a certain length if `StreamReader` constantly has data.

---

For problem #2, during cleanup, Python uses the assigned loop for the current thread. Under the hood, `asyncio.run()` and `asyncio.get_event_loop()` assigns the loop to the main thread. When it doesn't find a loop, all hell breaks loose.

If you wish to assign it yourself, you can do so like that:

```
def run():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    task1 = loop.create_task(put())
    task2 = loop.create_task(get())
    loop.run_forever()
```

Keep in mind you're still missing some manual cleanup (i.e. `shutdown_asyncgens` and `shutdown_executor`) but that's for a different topic. Overall, using `asyncio.run()` is usually the correct choice.

---

I'm unable to reproduce problem #3, both `await task1` and `await task2` work flawlessly.